# how to convert string to number without using library function

Tags: java

Suppose i want to create a method that takes a number as a string and return its number form. Like

```
getNumber("123456");

public int getNumber(String number) {

    //No library function should used. Means i can't do Integer.parseInteger(number).

} //end of getNumber()
```

How can i implement that method like

```
public int getNumber(String number) {

    for (int i=0; i<number.length; i++) {

    char c = number.getCharacter(i);
    ///How can i proceed further

    } //end of for()

} //end of getNumber()
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "library function" ? You can't use the Integer class ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Without using a library function, subtract the character `'0'` from each numeric character to give you its `int` value, then build up the number by multiplying the current sum by 10 before adding the next digit's `ìnt` value.

#### Java 7

```
public static int getNumber(String number) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
        result = result * 10 + number.charAt(i) - '0';
    }
    return result;
}
```

#### Java 8

```
public static int getNumber(String number) {
    return number.chars().reduce(0, (a, b) -> 10 * a + b - '0');
}
```

This works primarily because the characters `0-9` have consecutive ascii values, so subtracting `'0'` from any of them gives you the offset from the character `'0'`, which is of course the numeric equivalent of the character.

---

Disclaimer: This code does not handle negative numbers, arithmetic overflow or bad input.

You may want to enhance the code to cater for these. Implementing such functionality will be instructive, especially given this is obviously homework.

---

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getNumber("12345"));
}
```

Output:

```
12345
```

Comment: what is the line `result = result * 10 + c - '0'` actually doing ?

Comment: I must admit this is far better than my version :)

Comment: @Basit: i suggest you take a piece of paper and do the math for a few small numbers. It's harder to explain than to understand.

Comment: @Basit I've given a brief explanation of what's going on - see edited answer

Comment: @Aaron Digulla i did the math and understood how this is working:) @Bohemian Can you please explain what is mean by ` offset from the character '0'` .

Comment: @Basit offset (you could google this) means "how many bytes along from"

Comment: Thank you :) your code is very simple to understand. Thanks :)

Comment: @Bohemian What if the string content is a decimal value like `123.456`?

Comment: @Shashank this code only handles integers, but it wouldn't be hard to modify it to handle a decimal point. When you hit the dot, you would stop multiplying by 10 each iteration and instead divide the next digit by increasing powers of 10.

Comment: Hi @Bohemian. Could you please explain, why you're multiplying by 10? Thanks

Comment: @MichaelKors imagine the input `"456"`. After the first iteration `result` will be `4`. The next iteration `5` is added, so we first mutliply `4` by `10` so `result` will then be  `4*10 + 5 = 45`. The next iteration `6` is added, so we first multiply `45` by `10`, so `result` will be `45*10 + 6 = 456`, which is what we want.

Comment: @Bohemian, thanks mate, this is really fantastic explanation.

Answer (score -4):

Use `Integer.parseInt(str)`. Classes `Long`, `Short`, `Double` have similar methods too.

Comment: We are not allowed to use inbuilt library functions for this probem